# How can I make Module::Build install both X and X::Y?

Tags: perl, module, distribution

If I have a distribution with X and X::Y also in it, how do I make Module::Build install both the modules? I have put `X.pm` in `lib`, written a file `Build.PL` with the line

```
my $build = Module::Build->new
    (
     module_name => "X",
 );
```

This installs X OK, but how do I tell Module::Build to also include `X::Y` in the distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module::Build should automatically find and install both modules, though you should indicate to it (in Build.PL) which one the distribution name/version is taken from.

Try creating your distribution with [module-starter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/module-starter) and let it worry about the details?

```
module-starter -mb --module=X --module=X::Y --author=Me --email=me@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks. My directory structure was faulty (`X::Y` was not in `lib`).

Comment: That MakeMaker lets you stick Foo.pm and Bar/Baz.pm at the top level directory rather than in lib/ is a historical artifact which Module::Build joyously ditched.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that's not the reason for my problem. I put `X.pm` in `lib` as expected, wrote a file for Module::Build with `module_name => "X"`, and then I started trying to find how to tell Module::Build to also include `X::Y`. I didn't realise it would be found and installed automatically if I put it into `lib` until I read ysth's answer.